# Javascript: Array overriding the same values after assinging to JSON object

Tags: json, jquery, multidimensional-array

I am working with jquery ajax & the ajax response is multidimensional json array, I am assinging the JSON values to `coordinates` array & then assinging `coordinates` array to new JSON `coord_set`, after assinging all values to `coord_set`, It takes last array values to all,

for e.g.
the JSON result contains following values

```
obj[0]={125, 343, 456, 453},
obj[1]={345, 657, 234, 787},
obj[2]={980, 677, 657, 568}
```

after assinging to new JSON the values are:

```
coord_set[0] = {
                    fillColor : 'rgba(255, 234, 111 ,0.5)', 
                    data : [980, 677, 657, 568]
               }
coord_set[1] = {
                    fillColor : 'rgba(255, 234, 111 ,0.5)', 
                    data : [980, 677, 657, 568]
               }
coord_set[2] = {
                    fillColor : 'rgba(255, 234, 111 ,0.5)', 
                    data : [980, 677, 657, 568]
               }
```

This is my code:

```
  var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var j=0;j<obj.length;j++)
  { 
      for (var i=0;i<obj[j].length;i++)
      {
                  coordinates[i] = obj[j][i].how_many;
      }

      coord_set[j] = { fillColor : 'rgba(255, 234, 111 ,0.5)', data : coordinates };
  }
  alert(JSON.stringify(coord_set));
```

Please tell me, If I am doing Anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you getting an error? You didn't mention what problem you were having.

Comment: Not getting any error, the problem is last array of  ie. obj[2] values are getting assigned to all coord_set JSON array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a single `coordinates` array. You keep setting and re-setting the values in that same array, and you keep storing that same array in new elements of `coord_set`. To fix this, you just need to use a new `coordinates` array on each pass through the outer loop:

```
  for(var j=0;j<obj.length;j++)
  { 
      coordinates = [];      // <----- add this
      for (var i=0;i<obj[j].length;i++)
```

Comment: don't forget to make it a local variable, otherwise, you may have other surprises later...

Comment: Thanks a lot ruakh!!! Your fix made my day...... was stuck in this for the entire day today.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that JSON.parse actually works... but since you said you are using jquery, i would use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ personally...

Few things about your code:

- you never create a new object for coordinates, which is, by default, a global variable in JS. You must type:

  ```
  var coordinates = []; // before the for (var i = 0; ...
  ```
- where is this property "how_many" coming from? I don't see it in your first block of code... The code in your i loop should be:

  ```
  coordinates[i] = obj[j][i];
  ```
- finally, why do you need a copy of this transient object anyway? That should just do it:

  ```
  coord_set[j] = { fillColor : 'rgba(255, 234, 111 ,0.5)', data : obj[j] };
  // if you change your result set to give a code like that:
  obj[0]= [ 125, 343, 456, 453 ] // and not: obj[0]={125, 343, 456, 453}
  ```

Comment: From the OP's posted output, I'm assuming that the `how_many` stuff is actually fine. Probably the reason for copying the object is that the JSON stores the individual values in objects containing fields named `how_many`, whereas the OP just wants the values directly in `data`.